"Directive illegal error" when trying to run my code
I'm getting "Directive illegal error" when I try to run my code, can someoene help me please?
import cv2
import face_recognition

img = cv2.imread("messi1.jpeg")
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img)[0]



img2 = cv2.imread("messi2.webp")
rgb_img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_encoding2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img2)[0]


result = face_recognition.compare_faces([img_encoding], img_encoding2)
print("Result: ", result)


import cv2
import face_recognition
img = cv2.imread("messi1.jpeg")
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img)[0]
img2 = cv2.imread("messi2.webp")
rgb_img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_encoding2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img2)[0]
result = face_recognition.compare_faces([img_encoding], img_encoding2)
print("Result: ", result)
